# C/POSIX- pthread_t's blocking until task completion

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have a group of pthreads which all need to complete a task, then block until the last of them completes the task, then have all of them move onto the next task.  This happens for many tasks.

I was thinking of having a counter, which starts equal to the number of threads at the beginning of each task and, as each thread finishes a task, it decrements it safely with a mutex until the last thread makes it zero.  At the end of the task, all threads except the last one to complete would call pthread_cond_wait, and the last thread would call pthread_cond_broadcast to tell the other threads to move onto the next task.  Then the last thread would not wait, and would instead continue onto this task too.

However, I am left with one problem.  There is no guarantee that the second to last thread to decrement the counter will call pthread_cond_wait before the last thread calls pthread_cond_broadcast.

Is there any way in C and POSIX to handle this safely?

Comment: Even though you've found a solution using barriers, this sentence bothers me a bit: "There is no guarantee that the second to last thread to decrement the counter will call pthread_cond_wait before the last thread calls pthread_cond_broadcast". If you're correctly using condition variables there cannot be a race between the next-to-last and the last thread to decrement the counter because next-to-last thread should be holding the mutex while it calls `pthread_cond_wait()`. The problem you are concerned about is the reason you have to be holding the mutex when calling `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Comment: Yes, I understand this now, Sheu's solution pointed this out to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is barriers.

Initialize the barrier with the number of threads that will be waiting to reach it:

```
pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, N);
```

Then, each thread calls:

```
pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
```

The wait blocks until N threads are waiting on it, then all N wake up (conceptually) before any of them return from the wait call.

Comment: Holy crap that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Just got it implemented, worked perfectly with very little code. Thanks!

Comment: I love barriers. They're my favorite minimum-effort-to-use primitive in pthreads. They have some very nice uses (with N=2) for communicating between the parent thread and a newly-created thread for argument passing, etc. among other things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html).

---

**edit**: I guess you're trying not to destroy the threads.

[`pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) is supposed to be used with a mutex, as such:

```
int counter;                      // initialized to number of threads
struct pthread_cond_t condition;  // initialized previously
struct pthread_mutex_t mutex;     // initialized previously

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
counter -= 1;
while (counter > 0)
    pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);
pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

This will take care of the locking, counter, and condition, without having to use a separate semaphore.  (You're essentially implementing a "reverse semaphore" of sorts.)